# How can I download Apache server, PHP, and MySQL or other database on my Windows 7 machine?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, installation

I want to install Apache2.x and Php 5.4.x and MySQL or any other sort of database type onto my Windows 7 computer for hosting.

Does anyone have a good link to a tutorial for me to use? (If there is none then let me know or try to explain how I can install them.

I am basically starting from scratch as I have tried installing it several times, but unfortunately have had a lot of trouble getting things to work.

I appreciate your taking the time the respond,

Thanks

Comment: you could try WAMP package [http://www.wampserver.com/en/]

Comment: Try [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) package.

Comment: I agree with @SheikhHeera.. if you are trying it for the first time .. use xampp.. you dont have to install anything .. just download it unzip it.. save somewhere in C drive .. and start xampp control.. and you are ready to go...

Comment: I will check out WAMP package, as for xampp package, it has a lot of stuff! but I don't think it is for me, as I am only looking for the basic Apache + PHP + optional database.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I think for the simple purposes I will be using it for right now, (mainly Apache and PHP) I will use the tutorial posted by olijake. I have it installed right now and its just what I was looking for. I plan on doing more stuff later on and expanding, possibly on a different machine. From what I have seen from SheikhHeera and Dinish and Thanga, I think I might use XAMPP later on. The WAMP package LearneR mentioned looks pretty good for what I am doing right now also, I may try it out in addition.
Again, Thanks so much for all your guys' help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had this problem several weeks ago and it also took me forever to find a good tutorial.

Please refer to this [tutorial](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/).

The guide is extremely straight-forward and a good reference (I would bookmark it in case you ever needed to reinstall it)

Good luck,

Hope I helped you!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! I want to know how to install it manually to make sure I am only installing what I want to install.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can go ahead with XAMPP server which is more handy to all your requirements,

[Download from here](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/general/download_splash.cfm/xampp_for_windows_portable?software_id=3539&version_id=52166)

[Manual Of XAMPP](http://www.a3webtech.com/index.php/xampp.html)